# Recompiling generated class of WSDL without generating classes again using Maven

Tags: java, web-services, maven, wsdl

I included Client files to get port and some utils which commonly used at client in the jar which I generate to consume some web services, the problem I am facing is even for a small change in client files I need to generate and compile all the WSDL classes which has no modification.
Is there any way only to compile externally added classes and reuse already genarated class and create jar file.

Below is the pom.xml I am using

```
< project 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.logicsector</groupId>
    <artifactId>My-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>SOAP </name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>My-client</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Generate Java classes from WSDL during build -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <dataBinding>jaxb</dataBinding>
                                    <wsdl><!-- My WSDL URL http://domain:port/path--></wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-keep</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-exsh</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>true</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                    <BindingFiles>
                                        <BindingFile>${basedir}/binding.xjb</BindingFile>
                                    </BindingFiles>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Add generated sources - avoids having to copy generated sources to build location -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${basedir}/target/generated/src/main/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Build the JAR with dependencies -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <copy todir="../lib">
                                    <fileset file="target/my-client.jar" />
                                </copy>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: To clarify your question: Are you making changes to the source/class CXF files which were generated by Apache CXF?  Or are these changes coming from elsewhere in your project?

Comment: No, not the generated file, I added some extra packages and classes which will be in the generated jar file.